# VirtualBox error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am having a problem with VirtualBox: it won't start at all. I've tried reinstalling it, reinstalling dkms, purging it and reinstalling... but the problem persists. It displays an ugly error:

```
Premature end of data in tag VirtualBox line 8.
Location: '/home/rafael/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 41 (8), column 142.
/home/vbox/vbox-6.0.8/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[624] (nsresult VirtualBox::init()).

Código de Resultado: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Componente: 
VirtualBoxWrap
Interface: 
IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
Chamador: 
IVirtualBoxClient {d2937a8e-cb8d-4382-90ba-b7da78a74573}
```

I don't understand why this is happening or how to solve it. Could someone here help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works for me (having host:Debian 10)
was the following.

```
$cd ~/.config/Virtualbox
$rm VirtualBox.xml
```

I created a new machine (pointing to an existing VM)
and virtualbox managed to load successfully.